# Какой плагин использовать для функционала карты?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, карты

Подскажите возможно есть такой плагин, который позволяет при наведении на страну выделять ее другим цветом и увеличивать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот неплохой плагин для работы с картой и выглядит как вам надо http://jvectormap.com/